# How to detect if the .net remoting method hangs on the server app side?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

The remoting method of my .net remoting server app hangs sometimes when it gets called by the clients due to synchronization problem. These methods do some database read/write operation and return the results to the clients. It doesn't handle the database lock properly, so the hanging problem occurs. Unfortunately, we don't have the code of the module(implemented in c++ native code) that working with the database, so I have to find a workaround. 
I'm thinking if the server app could get informed when any of the remoting method hang, the server app could restart itself. In my case, restarting the server app is acceptable and I've already find a approach to do that. So are there any good ways to make server app know when the remoting method hangs?

Comment: you could execute the method asynchonously in a separate thread... if the execution time takes too much time you "know" that it hangs...

Comment: Any chance you'd stop using Remoting and start using a modern technology like WCF

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a timeout is good enough and you don't need to solve the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem):

```
public class TimeoutChecker
{
    private static Dictionary<Thread, DateTime> hashTimeouts
        = new Dictionary<Thread, DateTime>();
    static TimeoutChecker()
    {
        new Thread(CheckThread).Start();
    }
    protected static void CheckThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                foreach (DateTime t in hashTimeouts.Values)
                {
                    if (DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10 * 1000) < t)
                    {
                        //Perform recovery logic.
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
    public static void BeforeCall()
    {
        hashTimeouts.Add(Thread.CurrentThread, DateTime.Now);
    }
    public static void AfterCall() //be sure to execute in a finally...
    {
        hashTimeouts.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
    }
}
```

Here, BeforeCall and AfterCall would be in a wrapper outside the native calls, but inside the remote method invocations.

Of course, it's probably a much better idea to use synchronization before calling the native code to avoid deadlocks in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a timeout on your Remoting connection. When the time is up but the method from the server didn't return, Remoting automatically throws a RemotingException.

Comment: If the server didn't return(in case of dead lock or even infinite sleeping), the client could get the RemotingException. And what about at the server side? I am not sure that the server app would also got the RemotingException.

Comment: Right. Each remoting call that comes in from the client is executed on a separate thread taken from the built-in .NET thread pool. If that thread has a deadlock or sleeps infinitely it will never return. You should consider restructuring the code in the server method. @ebyrob has a good suggestion about synchronizing calls into the native C++ library.